# ActiveStorage::InvariableError using Mini Magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

```
<%= image_tag @supply.supply_photo.variant(resize: "400x400") %>
```

This is what I have in my view. @supply.supply_photo works for the orginal unsized image. My image is a webp... I turned it into a jpg with the same result. I feel like I am missing something simple but can figure out what I am missing.

The error I get is ActiveStorage::InvariableError

My log reads

```
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/cbaf86fd1070dd817c45101a6cf549f0" for ::1 at 2020-08-09 19:21:08 -0700
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/cbaf86fd1070dd817c45101a6cf549f0" for ::1 at 2020-08-09 19:21:09 -0700
Started GET "/supplies/1" for ::1 at 2020-08-09 19:21:57 -0700
Processing by SuppliesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/set_current_request_details.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SetCurrentRequestDetails>'
  Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "account_users" ON "accounts"."id" = "account_users"."account_id" WHERE "account_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "accounts"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/set_current_request_details.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SetCurrentRequestDetails>'
  Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "account_users" ON "accounts"."id" = "account_users"."account_id" WHERE "account_users"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "accounts"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/set_current_request_details.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SetCurrentRequestDetails>'
  Supply Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "supplies".* FROM "supplies" WHERE "supplies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/supplies_controller.rb:51:in `set_supply'
  Rendering supplies/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "Supply"], ["name", "supply_photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/supplies/show.html.erb:17
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/supplies/show.html.erb:17
  Rendered supplies/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.3ms | Allocations: 2886)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 6842)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (ActiveStorage::InvariableError):
    14:         <h5>Url</h5>
    15:         <%= @supply.url %>
    16:       </div>
    17:       <%= image_tag @supply.supply_photo.variant(resize_to_limit: "400x400") %>
    18:     </div>
    19:   </div>
    20: </div>
  
app/views/supplies/show.html.erb:17
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please add your `@supply` model (with the relevant parts) to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed my syntax around and now its working. In my model I had `has_one_attached :supply_photo` . What worked for me was changing "400x400" to  [400, 400]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue

```
<%= image_tag @supply.supply_photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [400, 400]) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file config/environments/production.rb add this line

`config.active_storage.variable_content_types = %w(image/png image/gif image/jpg image/jpeg image/webp)`

and on ubuntu install the webp application

`sudo apt-get install webp`

This worked for me